# oh-my-zsh No such file or directory even after installation

Tags: zsh, oh-my-zsh

I just installed oh-my-zsh. Things worked fine. Then I tried commenting out `export ZSH="~/.oh-my-zsh"`

After this, when I uncommented the line back, I keep getting the below error. However, "oh-my-zsh.sh" is present

```
(base) abc@def-MacBook-Pro .oh-my-zsh % source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh
source: no such file or directory: ~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh

(base) abc@def-MacBook-Pro .oh-my-zsh % ls -l ~/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh
-rwxr--r--  1 abc  staff  5927 Feb 11  2022 /Users/abc/.oh-my-zsh/oh-my-zsh.sh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because `~` is not expanded to the value of the `$HOME` variable when you quote it (with any type of quoting mechanism including single, double quotes, backslash, `$'...'`).

Thus you can use these commands instead:

```bash
export ZSH=~"/.oh-my-zsh"
```

or

```bash
export ZSH=~/.oh-my-zsh
```

or

```bash
export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"
```

---

Note that normally, `~` is not expanded after `=` either:

```
$ echo x=~
x=~
```

unless the `magicequalsubst` option is enabled:

```
$ set -o magicequalsubst
$ echo x=~
x=/home/me
```

But they are expanded in assignments:

```
$ x=~
$ echo "$x"
/home/me
```

And in relatively recent versions of `zsh`, `export` and other variable assignment builtins are treated as dual builtin / keywords, and their arguments are parsed as assignment.

Answer (score 0):

I am still now sure as to why this happened. However, reinstalling oh-my-zsh fixes the issue though.